# MDI or modal with one master background window

Tags: controller, modal-dialog, javafx-2, mdi

I've search the net for the concept of MDI forms in JavaFX or at least some form of it. But I do not find what I need or perhaps the words I search for is not correct. If I am searching for the wrong thing please let me know.

MDI-Multiple Document interfaces. Where you have a main window and you can launch individual windows that run inside of the main window. (Similar like photos is edited in Photoshop)

Or

Even how to have a main window and launch separate windows from the main window like… for example… Customers… Invoices. These windows don’t have to be open at the same time… but if you close them the main window should have focus again. (Similar like if you go to File>>Options in word-the options window is modal while the main word document is open) 
I might add that I want to do this in a windows (non web ) environment.

If anyone can share some good sites around how to work with multiple windows.

I asked my buddy at work and he asked me why would I want to do this in the first place.

Here is a few ideas (and please tell me if there are any better ways to do it:

1. The app launches with the main window all disabled and a separate window open on top with a username and password…
2. An app to open several icons and manages them

Comment: I did find a decent site where they explain about modality. So I would still like to know only about the MDI functionality

http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/02/modality-of-stage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real MDI framework for JavaFX 2.2.  You may be better off using the [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) or Eclipse platforms, and, if you wanted, embedding JavaFX Panels in them.

For a pure JavaFX version you might take a look at customizing [VFXWindows](http://mihosoft.eu/?p=365).

Comment: Thanks Jewelsea, I had a look at that... And it look awesome. I think for now I will rather stick to modal/show&hide of windows before I go to MDI. Just seems simpler